# below space not coming correctly using colortbl.sty and rowcolor

Tags: colortbl, rowcolor

My codes are:

```
\documentclass[executive,twoside, justified, symmetric, notoc,openany]{tufte-book} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{scrextend} 
\changefontsizes[12pt]{10pt}
\usepackage{array, calc}

\begin{document}

\colorlet{title}{red}

\begin{spacing}{.8}\small
\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{3cm}
@{\,\,\,\,\,\,\,}@{}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{5.8cm}
@{\,\,\,\,\,\,\,}@{}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{5.8cm}}

\multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{\color{title}\textbf{\normalsize{\uppercase{Some
Title}}}}\\
\addlinespace \addlinespace 

\rowcolor{title} 
\color{white} concept/notation & \color{white} description &
\color{white} example(s)\\ 
\end{tabular}
\end{spacing}

\end{document}
```

It produced the output like:

[image]

In this, some vertical white space comes above the text which are inside the color panel, but the below space didn't come, e.g.,

[image]

How can I achieve both are visually same? Please advise...

Note that I'm using `MikTeX V2.9` in `Win10`

I found that `para` mode (`p{5.8cm}`) caused the issue, but not sure how to fix that...Please advise...

Comment: you are getting the large space before because of the color command which actually produces an additional line. With `\leavevmode\color{white}` it would be smaller. To force larger space use a strut, e.g. `\rule[-5pt]{0pt}{15pt}`.